# Which ISOs support preseed?

Tags: system-installation, preseed

The desktop ISO doesn't seem to support preseed. Is it expected that only the Server ISO does?

Comment: Ubiquity does support (limited) preseeding.

Comment: Thanks, Ken.  When I had trouble with the standard directions, I did search for the answers, and I found conflicting information, including this link, whose author incorrectly suggests that the desktop ISO doesn't support unattended installation: http://gyk.lt/ubuntu-16-04-desktop-unattended-installation/ 

I've managed to make some progress on my own.  For anyone who comes across this post later: there are at least three different ISOs, and each has a different installer.

Comment: With the desktop ISO, you need to specify a location for the preseed file and also the "automatic-ubiquity" option.  A short document is here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation  

With the server ISO (which is not the one you will get from the prominent download links, but an ISO sometimes called the "alternative installer" or the "traditional installer" in smaller plain-text links), you need to specify the preseed location and also the "auto=true" option.  

With the live-server ISO, I have not found any working unattended installation options.